# Adding a relation row in a class when new user add to _User Parse

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want to add a row in a class "UserPrivileges" when new user adds to _User class.

I am doing this using cloud code, so far

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
if (request.object.isNew()) {
    var objectIdUser = request.object.objectId;
    var userPrivilege = Parse.Object.extend("UserPrivileges");
    var userPriv = new userPrivilege();
    userPriv.set("canSubmit",true); //canSubmit is a boolean field
    userPriv.save(null,{
    success:function(userPriv) { 
      response.success(person);
    },
    error:function(error) {
      response.error(error);
    }
  });
}
});
```

When I add new user to _User class nothing adds in "UserPrivileges", Am I missing something?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. [afterSave](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-aftersave-triggers) don't have a response. If you need a response, use [beforeSave](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers).
2. I would make sure the "UserPrivileges" class already exists on Parse.
3. What's the error message you are getting?